# Use Data from one file to another

Tags: python, python-3.4

I know there are a few like this on the site, but I couldn't get any to work. Was hoping to get help for my specific case.

What I need to do is have my number from the main part of my function run through five functions that I created in a different file.

This is the main part of my function, it has to be more then 1 and less then 20.

```
 k = int(input("Please input a number: "))

    def number(k):
        if k < 1:
            return False
        elif k > 20:
            return False


    number(k)

    p = number(k)
    print(p)

    import Functions_File
```

And these are the functions that it has to go through:

```
import Main_Part
root = int(input("Enter a number: "))
def square(root): 
    k = root
    return root**root 
square(root)

y = int(input("Enter a number: ")) 

def sum(y):
    k = y


  w = 1
    a = 0
    for w in range(1, y, +1): 
        a = w + a
    return a
sum(y)

answer = sum(y) 
w = int(input("Enter a number: ")) #Input for next function.


def DoubleRoot(w):

    Droot = 1
    Broot = 0

    for Droot in range(1, w+1):


    Broot = Broot + Droot ** 2 

    return Broot
    k = w
DoubleRoot(w)

Croot = DoubleRoot(w) #Creative name was creative. 

x = int(input("Enter a number: ")) #Input for the next function.


def factorial(x): #Gives you the factorial of an input. AKA 1*2*3*4*5

    k = x
    factor = 1
    for raptor in range(1, x + 1):
        factor = factor * raptor 
    return factor
factorial(x)

Function = factorial(x) 


q = int(input("Enter a number: "))

def truefalse(q): 
    k = q
    if q % 2 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
truefalse(q)

d = truefalse(q)
```

I've tried importing, and tried importing "From Square" etc, but it didn't work.
Edited to fix the coding. hope that's better.

Comment: Oh. Also, just for some more information. I also tried to make Q just a straight int, and make that int = k, but that didn't work either. My goal is to make the imported numbers show up as K.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and format your code properly using the `{}` button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're code isn't runnable as is, but here's a quick example that should help you fix your code:

#### main.py

```
import funcs
k = int(input("Number? "))
print(k, funcs.square(k))
```

#### funcs.py

```
def square(n):
    return n**2
```

Also, in each of your function cases, you define the function, then call it but don't do anything with the return value.  No reason to do this.  For example:

```
def number(k):
    if k < 1:
        return False
    elif k > 20:
        return False

number(k) # This calls the function but the result is lost.  Remove this.

p = number(k)
```